# is document.write blocking

Tags: javascript, document.write

I would like to insert a script into the page in a blocking way (can't use the src attribute of a script tag unfortunately). Would it block if i inserted the tag via document.write() on all browsers? I know this is a bad way of doing things, but i really need it to block the loading of other resources. Currently i'm doing:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(dynamic_script_tag_created_previously);
```

But this is not good since it's an asynchroneous load.

Thanks for reading and thinking about it :)

Comment: Loading asynchronously IS a problem. I need the script to load synchronously, not the other way around.

Comment: `document.write` writes scripts synchronously. It's useful for conditionally loading scripts.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same on all browsers?

Comment: Here are a few resources to explain the use case for document.write: * [Browser Script Loading Roundup](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/07/browser-script-loading-roundup/) * [Don't Docwrite Scripts](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/04/10/dont-docwrite-scripts/) * [document.write script block in Firefox](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/02/10/5b-document-write-scripts-block-in-firefox/) * [Delayed Script Execution](http://stevesouders.com/tests/delayed-script-execution.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example:

```
<script>
document.write('<!doctype html><html id="sanitized"><head>'
+ document.head.innerHTML + '</head><body>'
+ document.body.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
</script>
```

Will lock up the browser for a few seconds.