# Howto run function every few seconds that has return values?

Tags: javascript

How can I run this every few second , without blocking the rest of the pagefrom loading.

```
function Create() {
    var SomeArray = [];
    for ( var i=0; i<=1 ; i ++) {

    SomeArray[i] = (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    //alert(arr[0]);

    }
   return SomeArray;
}
var x = Create();
alert(x[0] + x[1]);
```

I was trying this var timer = setInterval(Create, 5000);  it prevent loading rest of the page.
 i  want to get new values every few seconds

Comment: It may have blocked because the function threw an error.

Comment: It shouldn't block, that is the best thing in callback, it will be a non-blocking call.

Comment: The problem is likely that you are trying to use `document.write()` in your function. If you use `document.write()` _after_ the page finishes loading/rendering (which will be the case here since your function won't be called for five seconds) it tends to replace the current document. Try appending the delayed text to a specific element (or to the end of the body) instead.

Comment: document.write is block, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585347/is-document-write-blocking

Comment: Seeing `document.write` is like going back to the 00s'.

Comment: I removed document.write . it did remove the block but  its not running teh the function every few seconds

Comment: Also, this `for ( i=0; i<=1 ; i ++)` is dangerous because `i` is an implicit global variable.

Comment: How can i run that function every few seconds using the set interval

Comment: @user244394 - can you create some code that has a purpose to it to run every few seconds?  Your current code does nothing when run by `setInterval()` because you can't return a value from the callback passed to `setInterval()` (well technically you can return a value, but it doesn't do anything or go anywhere).  Why don't you explain what problem you're really trying to solve rather than some theoretical exercise that we have now that doesn't actually do anything.  It's much easier to provide a useful answer to a real problem.

Comment: A simple function like this running every 5 seconds is unlikely to block anything. The issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: @jfriend00   - I am trying to print/output the new random values returned by the function every few second. It not blocking anything anymore. It just not runing every few second so i can get new values everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval()` can be configured to repeatedly call any function you designate at whatever time interval you request.  But, you can't retrieve a return value from that function.  Instead, you need to process the results from within the callback that you pass to `setInterval()` or call some other function and pass the results you generate inside the callback.  This is how asynchronous functions work in JavaScript.  I've provided several examples below of your options:

If you just want to generate two random decimal values between 1 and 10 (inclusive) every 5 seconds, you can do that like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var rand1 = (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var rand2 = (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    // now insert code here to do something with the two random numbers

}, 5000);
```

If you wanted the random values to be integers (which is more common), then you would do this:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;

    // now insert code here to do something with the two random numbers

}, 5000);
```

---

If you want to call a function and pass it those two random numbers, you can do this:

```
function processRandoms(r1, r2) {
    // code here to do something with the two random numbers
}

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    processRandoms(rand1, rand2);
}, 5000);
```

---

You can then stop the recurring interval at any time with this:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic example would be:

```
var counter = 0;
var timerRef;
var increment = function() {
    counter += 1;
    console.log(counter);
    timerRef = setTimeout(increment, 1000);
}

setTimeout(increment, 1000);

// clearTimeout(timerRef);
```

Please avoid `document.write` refer the [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN2hKN1wed0) for further details.

Comment: Why not `setInterval()` as in the OP's code? No need to change to `setTimeout()` in this case.